# How to get data param on the destination page from Ajax response call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I am Opening dynamically a page using Ajax, to prevent browser refresh. It opens and it runs scripts on the destination page. but before executing the script, I want them to retrieve the parameters like request.querystring but in Javascript.

This is my code that opens the page.

```
    function cargarPagina(para1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tarea.aspx",
            context: document.body,
            data: { "p1": para1 },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (responseText) {

                $("#maincontent").html(responseText);
                $("#maincontent").find("script").each(function (i) {
                    if ($(this).text() != "") {
                        $("#maincontent").find("#hola").val(para1);

                        //alert(para1); //eval($(this).text());
                    }


                });
                },
                async: true
            });
    }
```

After that, the tarea.aspx opens and executes scripts blah blah.

But before executing scripts, I want to get the "para1" value that was sent within the ajax POST call.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a POST not to the page, but to a *server*. The server then looks at your POST and says "oh, it looks like this is the page that you are requesting", and serves up some html content. The javascript on that served up page does not have any knowledge of the original POST, or how it (the page) came to be created.

If you want to get the POST parameters into the destination page, you must handle the POST request on the server, and then write the parameters in to the output page, via ASP.net or PHP or whatever scripting language you are using.

Alternatively, you could use GET instead of POST, and then the parameters would be available in the URL